# Cocos2dx ,SdkBox-IAP issue ,

Tags: java, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am getting following issue in SDKBox-IAP, I am working on cocos2d-x 3.7.1 , How can I change in .Jar file to remove this:-

> FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 223
>    Process: com.blacklight.spidersolitaire, PID: 16491
>    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.ArrayList.iterator()' on a null object reference
>       at com.sdkbox.plugin.SDKBoxIAPGooglePlay.restorePurchase(SDKBoxIAPGooglePlay.java:257)
>       at com.sdkbox.plugin.IAPWrapper.nativeOnInitialized(Native Method)
>       at com.sdkbox.plugin.IAPWrapper.access$000(IAPWrapper.java:9)
>       at com.sdkbox.plugin.IAPWrapper$1.run(IAPWrapper.java:26)
>       at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1501)
>       at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1278)

Comment: Check if you added the support libraries

Comment: Can you please sepecify,which support library I should use?

Comment: v4 and probably v7 appcompact  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_support_library.htm

Comment: These library I am v4 i am using , I think there is some problem in jar file of this sdk::IAP

Comment: Remove googleplay sdk from iap and get try the latest from google

Comment: Can you please post me the link for downloading new pluginGoogleplay.jar ?

Comment: Use the one in your android sdk folder

Comment: ok thanks,I will check that